# Eclipse Oxygen installation error OS X 10.11.6

Tags: java, eclipse, crash, osx-elcapitan, eclipse-oxygen

I'm trying to install Eclipse Oxygen on a clean install of OS X El Capitan (10.11.6). For some reason the installer crashes on launch:

Error log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Registry Directory not available: /Users/bjornschonrock/.p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry.
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(LazyProfileRegistry.java:236)
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(LazyProfileRegistry.java:227)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry.internalGetProfile(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:262)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry.getProfile(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:186)
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl.getCurrentProfile(AgentImpl.java:374)
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl.initializeProvisioningAgent(AgentImpl.java:576)
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl.getProvisioningAgent(AgentImpl.java:615)
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl.getProfileRegistry(AgentImpl.java:314)
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl$1.initializeFirstTime(AgentImpl.java:133)
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.PersistentMap.load(PersistentMap.java:111)
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl.<init>(AgentImpl.java:180)
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentManagerImpl$1.createElement(AgentManagerImpl.java:91)
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentManagerImpl$1.createElement(AgentManagerImpl.java:1)
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.PersistentMap.addElement(PersistentMap.java:151)
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentManagerImpl.addAgent(AgentManagerImpl.java:221)
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentManagerImpl.restoreBundlePool(AgentManagerImpl.java:373)
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentManagerImpl.getDefaultBundlePool(AgentManagerImpl.java:309)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleInstallerDialog.enablePool(SimpleInstallerDialog.java:398)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleInstallerDialog.createUI(SimpleInstallerDialog.java:304)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.AbstractSimpleDialog.show(AbstractSimpleDialog.java:139)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication.run(InstallerApplication.java:250)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication.start(InstallerApplication.java:408)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
```

https://paste.md-5.net/pupakogula.coffee

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Note that Eclipse Oxygen (4.7) is three releases out of date, the current release is SimRel 2018-12 (4.10) (released last Wednesday)

Comment: I guess that won't work for El Capitan. I can't even get Oxygen to work.. https://justpaste.it/24nsr

Answer (score 0):

Solved by correcting the paths in `~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.oomph.p2/defaults.info`